# How can I add my application to Tomcat in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven

I have a web app built with Maven. 
Most of the time, I built the application using Intellij IDEA, but now I want to import the application in Eclipse to see something in this IDE.

After `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, I add in Eclipse the app, but when I try to add the app to the server (tomcat), I receive:

```
There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server
```

Solutions?

Comment: In my case, without knowing why, simply creating a new Eclipse workspace and running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` fixed this for the very same code and resources from CVS. (Maybe an `eclipse -clean` would have fixed this too?)

Answer (score 50):

You need the project to have a Eclipse Dynamic Web Module facet. You can try doing this via the project properties dialog and looking at project facets, then clicking the appropriate check box. This may not be available however, so you may need to do the next thing.

Create a backup of your project and follow [the directions at dzone.com](https://dzone.com/articles/converting-java-project-dynami). This'll allow you to modify the project facets via your eclipse .project file.

Keep in mind, once you add those facets, you cannot change them back via Eclipse. Definitely make sure you have a backup before starting.

Comment: Addendum:If you already have the project facets options avaliable but can't add the web module, go down to the check box area on the Facets choice and right click. A dialog menu with the phrase "unlock" will come up, allowing you to add the Dynamic Web Project Facet to the project.

Comment: For what it's worth: I had the Dynamic Web Module installed.  However, in my pom.xml I had org.eclipse.wst.common.component defined, but had a comment around the ![CDATA] content as a temporary hack.  as soon as I removed the comment (in fact, removed the whole <file> definition) I was able to see the EAR in the add/remove menu.

Answer (score 34):

This step worked for me:

Right-Click on the Project Name, then
  Maven-->Update Project.. 
  Click OK

After doing this I was able to see my project in Add/Remove Programs.

As mentioned somewhere else adding Eclipse WTP didn't do any good, however I performed the above step after I had already added Eclipse WTP, so I am guessing that may not be needed. 
This was done for Eclipse Juno.

Hope this helps someone.

Edited: You can follow this link as above mentioned I think might have needed WTP and that add a lot of other things into the workspace.

http://blog.teamextension.com/maven-as-eclipse-dynamic-web-module-556

Comment: Sincere thanks, this worked for me when an eclipse restart wouldn't!

Answer (score 6):

1. Check whether `Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP` is installed. If not, install it from Eclipse Marketplace
2. After installation restart Eclipse
3. Right click your project and `Maven--> update project configuration`
4. Delete tomcat and re create tomcat (clean tomcat,add your project,publish and enjoy)

Answer (score 6):

I've got Tomcat 6, Java 1.6, and was trying to get it to work in Eclipse Juno Service Release 1's "internal server" (whatever that's called.)  Here's what I did that worked for me:

(Found these instructions at http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-ide-tomcat-version-6-0-only-supports-j2ee-1-2-1-3-1-4-and-java-ee-5-web-modules/)

1. I should point out that I followed ClutchDude's instructions to make my project a Dynamic Web Module facet.  It didn't work on its own for me, but maybe it was part of making it work in the end.
2. Using Eclipse (or other text editor), open the file

   .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
3. Find the line that reads

   `<installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/>`
4. 3.0 is for Tomcat 7.x (so says mkyong.)  Change it to 2.5 (or 2.4).

I restarted Eclipse and it worked for my project.

Comment: I'm back three years later.  I started a new Eclipse workspace, which gave me a new .settings directory.  I was told again that there weren't any projects I could add to my server.  I followed other instructions here to update my Maven project, and that worked.  It gave me the error "Preference node 'org.eclipse.wst.validation' has been removed."  That doesn't seem to cause any problems, though.  (That's a simple text file of preferences in my old .settings directory.)  FYI.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this is happening is because eclipse by default looks for the deployment descriptor in the folder {project.home}/Webcontent/WEB-INF/web.xml where as the Maven puts them in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml.

So when you are trying to add your project onto the server eclipse cannot find a deployment descriptor and hence you get the annoying message.

This can be solved by adding the following entries in *.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common* which can be found in

1. Project home folder in your workspace if it is a new maven project.
2. The folder where you already imported from if you are using Import -> Maven projects.

Make the following changes in to the org.eclipse.wst.common

1. wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/. Add this entry.
2. Edit --> property name="java-output-path"

Please check the following link from more details. http://java.dzone.com/articles/webapps-eclipse-and-maven. 
The comments section has an excellent example with a working project.

Comment: Thanks this works! Spent lots of time trying to figure out why my dynamic web project would not get deployed on eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was fixed for me my installing additional eclipse modules. in particular, the ones related to m2e-wtp. just do a search for `m2e` in the plugins search listing for your version of eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If you face an error like "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server",
then

1) Go to the META_INF of your websvcsEAR and go to the application.xml.
2) Goto modules-> clickDetails and add the module that is existing. i.e., some EAR which your project demands.
3) Click ok
4) Now go to your server -> right click -> add and remove -> add your EAR.

Comment: How exactly does it help? Tomcat doesn't support EARs at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need add your application to the server's configuration. I think that you must use m2e eclipse plugin in order to launch the app.

For example, in your eclipse you will see a contextual menu called "Run as" if you right-click on your pom file. You can clicking on "Maven build" and Maven will download all the information needed to start tomcat.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
 mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

in command line in the folder where I had my pom.xml. Then I refreshed the project in eclipse IDE. After that I was able to add my project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by removing my EAR project from my Eclipse workspace, then re-importing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with a Spring and maven project, i got it that way:

- Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
- Java 1.8
- Tomcat 7

Yes, go to Project Properties >> Facets >> select Dynamic Web Module but **dont apply yet!!!**

Right under, it should appear a link Further Configuration Available. Click on it, otherwise one will have to edit .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component manually. Update source directory to src/main/java. ([source](https://wiki.base22.com/btg/how-to-create-a-maven-web-app-and-deploy-to-tomcat-fast-27033760.html))

Then in Facets window check Java - mine was pointing to 11 even though i don't have Java 11 installed or configured like a JRE runtime. I could only add/remove when changed to 1.8. ([source](https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-ide-tomcat-version-6-0-only-supports-j2ee-1-2-1-3-1-4-and-java-ee-5-web-modules/)). Note: That was really the problem, why don't Eclipse get this configuration automatically from the project?

Finally Eclipse creates some directories like WEB-INF and META-INF, just delete them.