# How to deploy a maven project in tomcat within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven

I have been trying to deploy a project that I created within eclipse but when I right click on the tomcat server and click "Add and Remove...", I got the message "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server".

From what I understand it has something to do with the facets? I am not really sure to understand what is going wrong here.

Here is what I did for know:

- I created a Maven project.
- executed mvn eclipse:eclipse through the command line on the folder of the project
- installed m2e
- tried to add the project to the tomcat server

Comment: [similar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797212/how-can-i-add-my-application-to-tomcat-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use either `mvn eclipse:eclipse` OR m2e, but not both.  m2e has gotten MUCH better in the last couple years, so that's what I would suggest.

- Make sure you are using Eclipse for Java EE, otherwise you will need to install other plugins like WTP
- Install m2e.
- Install maven integration for wtp (from the eclipse marketplace)
- make sure the artifact type for your project is war
- Import Existing Maven Project in eclipse and browse to your pom to import the project.

It should give the correct facets to your project so it looks like a web project.