# There are No resources that can be added or removed from the server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat6

I have created a Dynamic web project, but I am not able to deploy it into
 Apache Tomcat Server 6.0. I am getting this error when I try to deploy my project:

> There are No resources that can be added or removed from the server.

Comment: how you are deploying manually or through eclipse...need details....

Comment: @AbhishekMishra:while hitting http://localhost:8080/ itself i am getting "http status 404 Error

Comment: in web.xml check whether their is any welcome file is there or not ..??

Comment: Follow the instructions given in this [question's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797212/how-can-i-add-my-application-to-tomcat-in-eclipse%EF%BB%BF) answer

Comment: @AbhishekMishra: i can see web.xml file under server it has  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

Comment: I hope these file is not exist you project,so either delete that or create the anyone file and remove all other remaining....

Answer (score 107, accepted):

For this you need to update your Project Facets setting.

> Project (right click) ->  Properties -> Project Facets from left
>   navigation.

If it is not open...click on the link, Check the Dynamic Web Module Check Box and select the respective version (Probably 2.4). Click on Apply Button and then Click on OK.

[image]

Comment: don't see java 11 there

Answer (score 14):

Check whether your Java version is compatible with the project. Right click the project>>Properties>>Project Facets>>Java check the version is compatible with your project.

Comment: This ans might be useful because I did the same mistake while selecting the version of Java.. Thanks!

Comment: don't see java 11 there

Answer (score 7):

if your project maven based, you can also try updating your project maven config by selecting project. Right click project> Maven>Update Project option. it will update your project config.

Answer (score 6):

I used `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` in command line in the folder where I had my pom.xml. Then I refreshed the project in eclipse IDE. After that I was able to add my project.

Comment: Is this for an older version of maven (not m2e)?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is incompatible web application version with the targeted server. So project facets needs to be changed. In most of the cases the "Dynamic Web Module" property. This should be the value of the servlet-api version supported by the  server.

In my case,

I tried changing the web_app value in web.xml. It did not worked.

I tried changing the project facet by right clicking on project properties(as mentioned above), did not work.

**What worked is:**
Changing  **"version" value as in jst.web to right version** from

**org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file**. This file is present in the **.setting folder under your project root directory**.

You may also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122336/cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0)

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find the Dynamic Web Module option when I clicked on the link, then I have installed Maven(Java EE) Integration for Eclipse WTP from the Eclipse Marketplace.Then, the above steps worked.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error even though the Project Facets were set appropriately. The problem was that the "Runtime Environment" property was not set on the server:

[image: Empty Runtime Environment for Eclipse Tomcat]

It simply needed to be set to the appropriate Runtime:

[image: Runtime Environment for Eclipse Tomcat]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is it is missing Dynamic Web Module facet definition.
Run the following at command line

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

After build is success, refresh the project and you will be add the web project to server.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was creating a

> .java-version

file with "oracle64-1.8.0.112" as the only entry ( use something that is 1.6+ )

Make sure you have dynamic web module facet turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project, select properties and then select "Targeted Runtimes". Check if Tomcat is selected here.

[image: Targeted Runtimes]

Answer (score 0):

First check Project Facets setting as most replies had been answered.

Then check the Runtime Server is also aligned with the appropriate JRE.

In my case, I updated project JRE System Library and JDK compiler to 1.8,
but original Tomcat server is setting up on JRE 1.7,after upgraded to 1.8,the issue is resolved.
[image]