# static web project eclipse tomcat no resources added or removed

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

There's a few questions about this but they all seem to be for dynamic web projects.  The solution is to check the Dynamic Web Module check box in project facets and to make sure the version of the module is compatible with the server being used.  I'm getting 
**There are No resources that can be added or removed from the server**
when clicking the add/remove button on a tomcat 8 or tomcat 7 server with a static web project in my workspace.  The Static Web Module is checked under project facets and the version next to the project facet is blank.
How do I add my static web project to a tomcat 8 server in eclipse?

Comment: The question was answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624782/there-are-no-resources-that-can-be-added-or-removed-from-the-server

Comment: That answer didn't work for me, I said that in the question